# How to get Pass/Fail for condition based on multiple rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with multiples rows. I just want to get Pass/Fail based on condition (Please see condition picture). It must go through all the rows that match bonus = $600 (also should check the GP % Goal and NSP, if bonus matches).

I tried this using IF/AND condition, it will give for each line. Hopefully, this make sense. Can anybody please tell me hot do this?

I also shared a sample file with with data.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MAbPEiODxxsmgpgu0Pg218GcEbMJTer/view?usp=sharing

[image]

Condition:

[image]

For Example, 
Result = "Pass"

[image]

[image]

In the above picture, for bonus 600 should be **Pass**, but below picture NSP score is below 85% and GP % Goal is low too, it should show as **Fail** even though other rows met the condition.

Result = "Fail"

[image]

[image]

Note - The way I tried (I am just testing with simple formula):

```
=IF(AND(Q2=600,L2>85%),"Yes","No")
```

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55621467/edit) to include the formula you did try?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I added the formula. Its very simple. It gives me result for each line, but I want summarize one. Thanks

Comment: So you want an overall result of "FAIL" if any of the rows fail?

Comment: @Michael, Yes that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula will return "Pass" if all rows with Bonus = 600 have all other conditions match too:

`=IF(COUNTIF(Q2:Q4,"=600")=COUNTIFS(Q2:Q4,"=600",L2:L4,">0.85",K2:K4,">1.05"),"Pass","Fail")`

Comment: How do I give the range, For Ex. GP % Goal (Column K) should be > 100% and <= 104.99%? I also have range for NSP (Column L) too. 

I tried like below did not work
`=IF(COUNTIF(Q2:Q4,"=600")=COUNTIFS(Q2:Q4,"=600",H2:H4,"=Store Manger",L2:L4,">0.95"& "<=0.99",K2:K4,">1.05" & "<=1.0499"),"Pass","Fail")`

Can you please let me know, this is the last peice I ma stuck on. 
Thank you

Comment: Hey @Michael,

Your formula only work for one logic of mine (Bonus = 600).Everything else showing me as Fail (Specially GP % to Goal between <85% , NPS  >85%). When I filter it out from data sheet it is matching the criteria. 

If you have a minute can please check my file. I did the formulas in excel sheet. I really appricate your time and help. Thank you so much 

(https://drive.google.com/file/d/15MAbPEiODxxsmgpgu0Pg218GcEbMJTer/view)

Comment: Your question only asked about 600. It's possible to handle multiple scenarios, but the formula would only work on 1 row at a time, so you'd have to add it as a separate column. Do you want a solution for that?

Comment: @ Michael, I added a unique key. Then it works. Again, thank you so much for your help.